# "Unterminated string" when including quote in string literal on Turbo C compiler

Tags: c, string, character, turbo-c

I have this on my program and it shows an error saying : Unterminated string.

```
char Tok[63][63] = {"%%##","\""};
```

Is there other way to declare the double quotation mark as a string?

Comment: Which platform and compiler are you using?

Comment: That explains a lot, because that passes fine on both clang and clang++ 3.3. If you could have chosen a worse C compiler, I'm pressed to see how. The last Turbo C (2.0) was released literally a quarter-century ago.

Comment: It was a requirement for a project so I need to stick to the compiler.

Comment: Replace it with the hex equivalent (byte value) - for example char(0x22) or similar.

Comment: Thanks prabindh that answers my question.

Comment: Now that I added more elements to the array it doesnt work. It only worls when the byte value is in the end of the array.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in Turbo C. I have tried:

```
char Tok[63][63] = { "%%##", "\"" };

int
main (int argc, char **argv)
{
  return 0;
};
```

on gcc, in normal mode, C89 mode, and C99 mode with `-Wall` and it compiles without errors (*). I have also manually reviewed the string and there is no way it is unterminated.

I suggest you use octal within your string literal, i.e.

```
char Tok[63][63] = { "%%##", "\042" };
```

and see if Turbo C likes that.

(*) = NB `return 0` is not good practice from `main()` - just there to ensure the code compiles without warnings in the simplest way possible

Comment: This works better than the above answer because you can add nex to it a new element to array without getting error. except that the octal value of double quote is 042.

Comment: Oops - hex/octal thinko - fixed.